# Do I need a ground rod connected to my panel in my mobile home?

Tags: electrical

There is a meter pole with the main disconnect and ground rod at the bottom, feeding the mobile home with 4 wires, 2 hot, 1 neutral, 1 ground.  Neutral and ground are bonded at the meter pole main disconnect, does the mobile home need an additional ground rod connected to the panel inside the home?

Comment: How far is the mobile home from the meter pole?

Comment: I take it this mobile home's been set on a permanent foundation, with the towing gear and axles removed?

Comment: I am not sure if it is a needed or a must have requirement, but it will not hurt and will give better grounding to your system.  The requirements for grounding can be different for different locations.

Comment: What city/state are you in? As @crip659 noted, code requirements vary by locale...